# jQuery setTimeout of a hover function

Tags: jquery, timeout

my .hover function work fine but now the .hover function needs to wait 2 seconds to start but something isnt working with my code.

### JS Code

```
setTimeOut(function(){
        $('#sectionNews').hover(
            function() {
                
                    $(this).find('.underlay_wrapper').animate({
                        height: '85px', opacity: '1'
                    }, 1000 );
                
            },function() {
                $(this).find('.underlay_wrapper').animate({
                    height: '0px', opacity: '0'
                },500);

            }
        );
    }, 200);
```

Comment: Do you want your code to run two seconds after user hovered the mouse over the `#sectionNews`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want the hover code to start 2 seconds after hovering you must put the setTimeout inside hover

```
var tOut = null;
$('#sectionNews').hover(function () {
   var $this=$(this);
  tOut=  setTimeout(function () { //Here
        $this.find('.underlay_wrapper').animate({
            height: '85px',
            opacity: '1'
        }, 1000);
    }, 2000);
}, function () {
    var $this = $(this);
    clearTimeout(tOut);
    setTimeout(function () {//here also if you want it to setTimeout when hover out
        $this.find('.underlay_wrapper').animate({
            height: '0px',
            opacity: '0'
        }, 500);
    }, 2000);
});
```

**Update**

You could use .delay(2000) instead of setTimeout for animating elements

```
$('#sectionNews').hover(function () {
        $(this).find('.underlay_wrapper').delay(2000).animate({
            height: '85px',
            opacity: '1'
        }, 1000);
}, function () {
        $(this).find('.underlay_wrapper').delay(2000).animate({
            height: '0px',
            opacity: '0'
        }, 500);
});
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/BQ8RY/)

Comment: Thanks anton but the funktion doesnt start now.

Comment: @fr3d Are you getting any errors in the console. Is #sectionNews dynamically added to the html?

Comment: No, there are no errors. SectionNews is not dynamiclly loaded.

Comment: @fr3d I've updated the answer take a look at the demo

Comment: But one little problem, the hover div got the full width of the browser, so if i got quick from the top to the bottom with the mouse cursor, the function starts all the time.

Is there a way to start the slide function only if i stay min 1 second on the element "#sectionNews" or else the function does not start?

Comment: Updated first answer @fr3d the reason why setTimeout did not work was because this isn't scoped in the function here is a demo i've also added clearTimeout so you must be in the hover for 2 seconds http://jsfiddle.net/BQ8RY/1/

Answer (score 0):

try like this

```
$('#sectionNews').hover(function () {
        var a = setInterval(function () {
            $(this).find('.underlay_wrapper').animate({
                height: '85px', opacity: '1'
            }, 1000);
            clearInterval(a);

        }, 2000);
    });
```

Comment: Why use setInterval when there is setTimeout?

Comment: @Anton sorry. I'm not familiar with that. Is there any problem with setInterval approach?

Comment: Well, i would say it's wrong to use setInterval like that even though it works because you are making the setInterval work like setTimeout

Comment: _"Is there any problem with setInterval approach?"_ - It's confusing, because normally `setInterval()` is intended for a function that will be repeated, whereas [`setTimeout()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/window.setTimeout) only runs the function once. Also it's longer than it needs to be because with `setTimeout()` you don't need to clear anything so there's no need for the `a` variable either (unless the timeout is to be cleared in the hover _out_ handler).

Comment: I´ve got a fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/zL5rS/2/
Here you can see the problem.