# How can I access $(this) in my hover function with setTimeout

Tags: jquery, hover, this, settimeout

I have this code to display a tooltip I created. It shows up on mouse hover, after a delay of 2 seconds.

```
/* Custom Shop Page Toolip */
var timeout;
$('.product-bottom-info-container').hover(
    var that = this;
    function(e) {
        timeout = setTimeout(function() {
            that.find('.product-custom-tooltip-container').css({
                display: 'inline-block',
                position: 'fixed',
                zIndex: '5000',
                margin: '10px',
                whiteSpace: "nowrap"
            }).position({
                my: "right top",
                at: "left bottom",
                of: e,
                collision: "fit"
            });
        }, 2000);
    }, 
    function() {
        clearTimeout(timeout);
        that.find('.product-custom-tooltip-container').hide();
    }
);
```

After calling `setTimeout()`, I am no longer able to access `$(this)`, which is referencing the **.product-bottom-info-container** selector.

So I tried to create a variable instead - `var that = $(this)` . I am getting an error **Unexpected token var** on that line.

I have also tried `var that = this`, and this also does not work.

How may I access `$(this)` inside of the `setTimeout()` function?

I've been reading all sorts of examples, [namely this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22069750/jquery-settimeout-of-a-hover-function), and it seems to have worked for some, but it's not working for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem with your code is a syntax error. While doing so, you are also not using `$` here:

```
/* Custom Shop Page Toolip */
var timeout;
$('.product-bottom-info-container').hover( // Here you should give your parameters, and you cannot have a ; here.
    var that = this;
    function(e) {
        timeout = setTimeout(function() {
            that.find('.product-custom-tooltip-container').css({
                display: 'inline-block',
                position: 'fixed',
                zIndex: '5000',
                margin: '10px',
                whiteSpace: "nowrap"
            }).position({
                my: "right top",
                at: "left bottom",
                of: e,
                collision: "fit"
            });
        }, 2000);
    }, 
    function() {
        clearTimeout(timeout);
        that.find('.product-custom-tooltip-container').hide();
    }
);
```

Changing your code to the below one should work:

```
var timeout;
$('.product-bottom-info-container').hover(function(e) {
  // 1. Wrap your this inside $().
  var that = $(this);
  timeout = setTimeout(function() {
    that.find('.product-custom-tooltip-container').css({
      display: 'inline-block',
      position: 'fixed',
      zIndex: '5000',
      margin: '10px',
      whiteSpace: "nowrap"
    }).position({
      my: "right top",
      at: "left bottom",
      of: e,
      collision: "fit"
    });
  }, 2000);
}, function() {
  clearTimeout(timeout);
  // 2. You can use $(this) here as it is the second function, and this refers to the element that triggered the event.
  $(this).find('.product-custom-tooltip-container').hide();
});
```

The two things that needs to be done are:

1. Wrap your `this` inside `$(this)`.
2. Use `$(this)` inside the `.hover()` function's second parameter.

Comment: Not sure why the down vote, worked for me. Thanks much